# cannot set session timeout longer after checking all other sites

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

After adding these settings in web.config for increasing session timeout:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424"
 stateNetworkTimeout="240" cookieless="false" timeout="240"></sessionState>

<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms name="site" loginUrl="login.aspx" timeout="9999999" 
    slidingExpiration="true" protection="All" cookieless="AutoDetect" 
    requireSSL="false" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" defaultUrl="default.aspx"> 
   </forms>
</authentication>
```

But the session of my webpage is always ended after 20 minutes. What did I miss?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also have found this one: http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article86.aspx but it will refresh the web page that I dont like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer here: http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article86.aspx by adding an iFrame and open a webpage just before session ends.

Answer (score 0):

> What did I miss?

The fact that IIS can recycle your application domain at any time. For example after a certain period of inactivity which IIRC is 20 minutes by default. Or if a certain memory usage limit or CPU threshold is reached by your application. All this is configurable in the application domain properties in IIS. And of course when IIS recycles your AppDomain, everything you might have stored into the memory (such as session) goes into the oblivion.

Comment: that means I have to change it on IIS not with web.config?

Comment: @devn, even if you change in IIS, there's no guarantee that your AppDomain will stay alive. You could use an out-of-proc session storage if you want your sessions to survive AppDomain recycles. There are 2 possibilities: StateServer or SQL Server. Read here about it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx. Or even better: don't use any session state at all. Simply set it to `model="Off"` an design a stateless and RESTful application application.